# Php Pregmatch want to extract year from string

Tags: php, preg-match

i want to extract the 'year' from string here is my string

```
clerk_eng2009
```

and

```
clerk_23-eng-2009
```

the result that i needed only 2009

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "clerk_eng2009";

    preg_match_all("/\d{4}$/", $str, $matches);

    echo $matches[0][0];

?>
```

Output:

```
2009
```

Comment: If `clerk_2300-eng-2009` is a possible string, `/\d{4}$/` (assumed the year is at the end) would be better.

Comment: Thank You  Rizier its help me alot :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
$num = intval( substr($str, strlen($str) - 4, strlen($str)) );
```

and that's it.
There's no point in using a regular expression (which is computationally expensive to calculate) in this string. It's simple to extract just the four last characters and then evaluate as an integer using `intval()`.

EDIT:

Another option (as it seems all values are delimited by a `-`) is to separate all values in a vector and then extract the one with the year:

```
$vector = explode( $str, "-");
$num = intval( $vector[2] ); // We use the third value, which is supposed to be the year
```